# It is not possible to trigger the scroll event once while another event is running

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

help with scroll who came across.
There is a div

```
<div
    ref={scrollContainerRef}
    onScroll={onScroll}
    classname="items">
```

Inside a component

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
const scrollContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
const onScroll = () => {
  if (isLoading) {
    console.log("loading exit");
      return;
  }
  const div = scrollContainerRef.current;
  if (div) {
    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = div;
    const isScrolledToEnd = Math.abs(scrollTop + clientHeight - scrollHeight) < 1;
    console.log(isScrolledToEnd, scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight);

    if (isScrolledToEnd) {
       getRequest();
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is that if I abruptly scroll up and down about 5 times, it seems to put all the events on the stack and call them one by one. How to make it so that when scrolling down while isLoading is true, then do not execute the scroll event and wait for an event from the user. Thank you in advance.

I tried to do so.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (isLoading)
     scrollContainerRef.current?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
   else scrollContainerRef.current?.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

    }, []);
```

And also in the onScroll function
scrollContainerRef.current?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
but it did not help